# SCJP Pre-Generics Concept

Tags: java

Given a pre-generics implementation of a method:

```
public static int sum(List list) {    
    int sum = 0;    
    for ( Iterator iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {     
        int i = ((Integer)iter.next()).intValue();     
        sum += i;    
    }
    return sum;    
}
```

What three changes allow the class to be used with generics and avoid an unchecked warning? (Choose three.)

A. Remove line 14.

B. Replace line 14 with `int i = iter.next();`.

C. Replace line 13 with `for (int i : intList) {`.

D. Replace line 13 with `for (Iterator iter : intList) {`.

E. Replace the method declaration with `sum(List<int> intList)`.

F. Replace the method declaration with `sum(List<Integer> intList)`.

This question is from SCJP and answer is ACF. But i choosed ABF. 
Can anyone explain why its C instread of B. If i use B , it will work or not? and why?

Comment: `B` would only work warning-free if you *also* changed line 13 to `for (Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )` - and that isn't an option as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int i = iter.next()` would only compile if you declared the iterator as `Iterator<Integer>`.

However, the foreach loop added in Java 5 means that if you have a `List<Integer>` and you want to iterate over it's elements, you can simply use `for (int i : list)` and skip having to create an iterator, call `next()` and `hasNext()` - the compiler will write that code for you.